# what is the impact of using large number of features compared to a small data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, random-forest, feature-engineering, boosting

I have time series data with 25 features and 181 observations, and the number of classes are 7. I used 3 models svm,random forest and xgboost to classify but the performance was really bad for each. i was wondering what is the impact of having this number of features for a small data, specially i have partitioned the data into 60:40 train-to-test! I would appreciate some explanation in this matter.

Comment: It is called overfitting. Think about how many parameters you would estimate if the model was a linear one. How exactly is your data structured?